# What is causing my macadamia nuts to have tiny holes in them and are then hollow inside?

Tags: pests

I have been growing a macadamia nut tree and have found tiny little holes in the nuts.  When I cut them open, they are hollow inside.  Are these rats eating the nuts?[image: Macadamia Nut One]

[image]